# Breifly seeing old image after setting new src with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, fade

I want to

1. Fade out the image
2. Preload a replacement image
3. Change the image source to display the new image
4. Fade in the (new) image

For some reason, though when the image fades back in there is a very brief moment where the old image is seen then replaced by the new image.  I don't think this is a timing conflict between image operations... what else would cause this flicker?

```
// old image: about.jpg
// new image: contact.jpg


$('#content').fadeTo(1500, 0.01, function(){
    var container = $(this);

    // gather image information
    var src = img.parent().attr('href');
    imgData = { 'alt': img.attr('alt'), 'src': src, 'cap': '' };

    // change background image & caption (after image has been cached)
    var imgSrc = sanitizeBackgroundImage( imgData );
    $.get( imgSrc, function(data) {

        // set background image src to preloaded image
        $("#content>img").attr({"src": imgData.src});
        $("#content>img").attr({"alt": imgData.alt});

        // update caption text
        $('#bottom-caption').html('<span>' + imgData.cap + '</span>');

        // fade image container back in
        console.log( 'before fadeIn: ' + $("#content>img").attr("src") );
        container.fadeTo(750, 1);                   
    });
});
```

The console correctly reads

```
before fadeIn: /images/large/contact.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to start fade-in at image load? I think fade-in is started before the image is fully loaded and displayed.

```
$("#content>img").load(function() { $('#content').fadeTo(750, 1); });

$('#content').fadeTo(1500, 0.01, function(){ 
  var container = $(this); 

  // gather image information 
  var src = img.parent().attr('href'); 
  imgData = { 'alt': img.attr('alt'), 'src': src, 'cap': '' }; 

  // change background image & caption (after image has been cached) 
  var imgSrc = sanitizeBackgroundImage( imgData ); 
  $.get( imgSrc, function(data) { 

    // set background image src to preloaded image 
    $("#content>img").attr({"src": imgData.src}); 
    $("#content>img").attr({"alt": imgData.alt}); 

    // update caption text 
    $('#bottom-caption').html('<span>' + imgData.cap + '</span>');  
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image will not be replaced *instantly*,as browser needs some time to load the image data and *only* then it will replace the old one. Wait untill image will be loaded and then do your `fadein`.